# How to enforce untyped columns in ExcelDataReader?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, dataset, xls, exceldatareader

**How do you prevent dates or times getting strictly-formatted?**

I'm reading an XLS file using `reader.AsDataSet`, and when the source data is `12/12/2014` then this generates an output of `12/12/2014 12:00:00AM`.

Also, when the source is for example `5:01:23 AM` then this generates something weird: `12/31/1899 5:01:23 AM`

Here's the function:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    IExcelDataReader reader = null;
    if (excelFilePath.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    }
    else if (excelFilePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    }

    if (reader == null)
        return false;

    var ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        UseColumnDataType = false,
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = false
        }
    });
```

How do we read in the XLS file into a DataSet without automatically *typing-concretely* the data?

Comment: I don't think, its weird. Looks like you need `timespan` column, instead you get `DateTime`. Datetime of course needs date part, so it adds it. Mat be, `AsDataSet` does not fit your case. You probably need to convert types in a loop. But I also see that date does seem coming from Excel, not converted. Otherwise it would be `1/1/0001 5:01:23 AM`

Comment: @T.S. can you give an example suggestion of how to read this?

Comment: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader `do {
   while (reader.Read()) {
    // reader.GetDouble(0);
   }
  } while (reader.NextResult());`

Comment: @T.S. sorry not understanding `reader.GetDouble(0)` - none of my data is a `Double`

Comment: Ok, but there must be `Reader.GetDate` etc. This is just a sample. Don't take literally. Look at definition https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/develop/src/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader.cs. So in your loop you'll do something like (depends what you need) `reader.GetDate(..).ToString("hh:mm:ss")` - this will give you string representation of timespan. You can fill string column in data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this situation you have all data you need in your result (as `DataSet`)!
So, I can suggest you to ignore that option in reading time and instead add any extra column to your result like below:

```
// `Copy` used to generate a new object
var dataTable = ds.Tables[0].Copy();

// create a new column with your own settings (like `TimeOnly`) and add it to your new DataTable
var newColumn = new DataColumn("TimeOnly", typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true };
dataTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);

// update your new column data based on other columns like `Column1`
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    var value = DateTime.Parse(row["Column1"].ToString()).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    row["TimeOnly"] = value;
}
```

HTH